I can't understand why user data isn't being entered into the database
I'm creating a discord bot that will enter user data from the server into the database, such as id, username, nickname and roles. For this I use discord.py and Supabase. It doesn't show any errors in the console.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from supabase import create_client, Client

url: str = "my_url"
key: str = "my_key"
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот запущен!")

    for  guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            post = {
                "id": member.id,
                "username": member.name,
                "nickname": member.display_name,
                "role": member.roles
            }

            response = supabase.table("usersDiscord").select("*").eq("id", member.id).execute()
            if response == []:
               response = supabase.table("usersDiscord").insert(post).execute()

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    post = {
        "id": member.id,
        "username": member.name,
        "nickname": member.display_name,
        "role": member.roles
    }

    response = supabase.table("usersDiscord").select("*").eq("id", member.id).execute()
    if response == []:
        response = supabase.table("usersDiscord").insert(post).execute()

bot.run("my_token")

Perhaps the problem occurs in the place where I am trying to check whether there is already a user with a given id in the database. The purpose of this check is that if such a user exists, then he is not added to the database, and if there is no such user, then he needs to be added.
response = supabase.table("usersDiscord").select("*").eq("id", member.id).execute()
    if response == []:
        response = supabase.table("usersDiscord").insert(post).execute()


Based on the supabase python client documentation, it looks like it returns JSON data or a dict, so the check for response == [] will never be true. Instead you should be checking something like len(response["data"]) == 0, or drop the explicit len() call and just check response["data"] implcitily.   Have to tried using logging to verify that your event functions are being run at all or to check the actual contents of response?

There could be several reasons why this is not working. On first sight it doesn't look like it's a code issue.

First (and most likely) I would check on the RLS policies (Enable Row Level Security (RLS)) and see if they are correcly setup (you should be able to read/write to the table you want to make operations to)

Another reason could be that you are saving on fields that are supposed to be of a format that is not correct (for example ID set to be INT(8) and you are saving a string there)

Another reason could be that the fields you are trying to write to are already propagated, or they are part of some other table constrain like a primary key on another table that doesn't have that entry.

Usually if there is an error on the Supabase side they tend to tell you what's going on with a reply message. Is there something in the logs that you forgot to post?


